# Creating new Attribute Label leads to Browser Crash

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, adminform

I have a Magento CE 1.7 project and when I go to "Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes" then click in any existing attribute.

Now, Tab "Manage Label/Option" on the section "Manage Options (values of your attribute)" I click on "Add Option", fill the field with any text and hit the button "Save and Continue Edit".

After that nothing else works anymore. The browser freezes and afterwards crashes. Has anyone else come across this issue and got it sorted?

Cheers.

Comment: This is working. Can you check log files?

Comment: So far I've found the problem relies on the javascript method "editForm.submit()". When we have too many fields it freezes and crashes the browser. Not sure quite yet how to solve it.

Comment: What browser are you using?  When you do it in Chrome, do you see any errors in the console?